# C++11 Function That Only Accepts String Literals?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11

I want to write a C++11 function that will only accept string literals as a parameter:

```
 void f(const char* s) { static_assert(s is a string literal); ... }
```

That is:

```
 f("foo"); // OK

 char c = ...;
 f(&c); // ERROR: Doesn't compile

 string s = ...;
 f(s.c_str()); // ERROR: Doesn't compile

 etc
```

Is there anyway to implement this?  The signature of the function is open to changes, as is adding the use of macros or any other language feature.

If this is not possible what is the closest approximation?  (Can user-defined literals help in anyway?)

If not is there a platform specific way in GCC 4.7 / Linux ?

Comment: What will you do with string literals that you cannot do with non-string-literals? And how about passing a `const char *const` variable initialised using a string literal? Or a `const char (&array)[]` reference to a string literal?

Comment: This is not possible, as string literals are just `char const[N]` arrays, and as such are indistinguishable from them.

Comment: Maybe using a user-defined string literal that converts to a type that has the data read-only when it is a this rvalue reference (so it can't be a named variable).  The goal is to enforce that the string is literally typed into the code at the point of call, and statically compiled into the application image.

Comment: deleted my answer as it accepted char array variables too... Would it be possible to use a template as in the other answer to accept char arrays and then use an rvalue reference to ensure that it couldn't accept a named variable directly to achieve a closer result?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling That isn't guaranteed even if you do pass a string literal. Example: `#include <stdio.h>` / `void f(const char *s) { printf(s); }` / `int main() { f("Hello, world!\n"); }` only causes `"Hello, world!"` (without the `'\n'`) to appear in the executable in a quick test on my system.

Comment: @hvd: No, I mean you pass a user-defined string literal, and make that the only way to construct the type.  How could you pass something else?  User-defined literals are a C++11 feature.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling Edited, does that make it clearer what I mean?

Comment: @hvd: Do you know what user-defined literals are?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling Yes, I do. What difference does that make here? If not even string literals are necessarily presented as is in the executable, why would any other literals be?

Comment: @hvd: Because you could construct a special type from the user-defined literal, and then only accept that special type as the parameter.  `SpecialType operator "" _foo(const char* str, size_t /*length*/)` and then define SpecialType in some way such that it can only be used as a temporary.  Then define `f(SpecialType)`

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling But how would that ensure that your string is "statically compiled into the application image"? That's what you said you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: @hvd: The const char* str parameter of `operator""` is compiled into the application image like a normal string literal isn't it?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling But my example shows that a normal string literal *isn't* compiled into the application image.

Comment: @hvd: I don't understand sorry.  You're saying that the `'\n'` is stripped from your `"Hello World\n"` string literal?  If so how is that relevant?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling What appears in my executable isn't my string literal. It's some bits (in this case, most bits) of my string literal, but not all of them. And I can change `f` to do nothing, to ignore its argument, and then no bits will appear in the executable.

Comment: @hvd: We're talking cross-purposes.  Yes the optimizer may strip some data so that the program is smaller but still functions *as if* the data was compiled in.  The point is to avoid the function being called with a string calculated at runtime, and for the parameter string to appear in the source code at the call site.

Comment: @hvd: It appears GCC glibc printf has implemented this feature somehow: printf issues a `warning: format not a string literal`.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: The warning about `printf` is implemented mostly inside the GCC compiler (and partly in Glibc headers thru appropriate `__attribute__`  annotations). So you need to extend GCC to make a similar check. See my answer.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling So you don't actually care whether the string literal appears in the application image. My comments were based on that, my second comment was a reply to your "The goal is to enforce that the string is literally typed into the code at the point of call, and statically compiled into the application image." In that case, I will rephrase my first question: how about other situations, that don't pass a string literal directly, but don't calculate a string at runtime either? A pointer/reference to a string literal, a simple `const char array[]`, etc.?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the closest you are going to get is this

```
template<int N>
void f(const char (&str)[N]){
  ...
}
```

It will compile with literals and arrays but not pointers.

Comment: You might be able to further prevent it from working with most non-literal arrays with clever use of `std::enable_if<>`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805011/how-to-detect-a-string-literal-with-type-traits for an example of what to put in the enable_if (although that question uses static_assert, it's the same concept).

Comment: Instinctively, I would use a std::size_t instead of a int as the template parameter, but I couldn't find a reference that would say to use one or the other. If someone has some insight...

Answer (score 4):

An alternative might be to make a GCC extension to check at compile time that your particular function is only called with a literal string.

You could use [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to extend GCC. MELT is a high-level domain specific language to extend the GCC compiler, and is very well suited for the kind of check you want.

Basically, you would add a new pass inside GCC and code that pass in MELT which would find every gimple which is a call to your function and check that the argument is indeed a literal string. The `ex06` example on [melt-examples](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-examples) should inspire you. Then subscribe to [gcc-melt@googlegroups.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/gcc-melt) and ask your MELT specific questions there.

<sup>Of course, this is not  a foolproof approach: the function could be called indirectly thru pointers, and it could e.g. have a partial literal string, e.g. `f("hello world I am here"+(i%4))` is conceptually a call with some literal string (e.g. in `.rodata` segment), but not in the generated code nor in the gimple.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I use this :

```
// these are used to force constant, literal strings in sqfish binding names
// which allows to store/copy just the pointer without having to manage
// allocations and memory copies
struct _literalstring
{
    // these functions are just for easy usage... not needed
    // the struct can be empty
    bool equal(_literalstring const *other) { return !strcmp((const char *)this, (const char *)other); }
    bool equal(const char *other) { return !strcmp((const char *)this, other); }
    const char *str(void) { return (const char *)this; }
    bool empty(void) { return *(const char *)this == 0; }
};

typedef _literalstring *LITSTR;

constexpr LITSTR operator "" _LIT(const char *s, size_t) {
    return (LITSTR)s;
}
```

Then you just declare your function like this :

```
void myFunc(LITSTR str)
{
    printf("%s\n", str->str());
    printf("%s\n", (const char *)str);
    const char *aVar = str->str();
    const char *another = (const char *)str;
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
myFunc("some text"_LIT);
```

If you do something like this:

```
myFunc("some text");
myFunc(aTextVariable);
```

you get a compiler error.