# How to detect a string literal with type_traits?

Tags: c++, c++11, string-literals, type-traits

How do I reliably static_assert on anything that isn't a string literal?

For example, in the following code, I've attempted to wrap the standard assert macro but statically reject anything for the message that's not a string literal (since anything but a string literal will not be displayed at runtime when the assert triggers).

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

#define my_assert(test, message)\
    static_assert(\
        (\
            !std::is_pointer<decltype(message)>::value &&\
            !std::is_array<decltype(message)>::value\
        ),\
        "literal string required"\
    );\
    assert((message, (test)));

int main() {
    my_assert(1 == 1, "one equals one");
    my_assert(1 == 2, "one equals two");

    {
        const char *msg = "one equals one";
        //my_assert(1 == 1, msg); // triggers static_assert
    }

    {
        const char msg[] = "one equals one";
        //my_assert(1 == 1, msg); // triggers static_assert
    }

    {
        const std::string msg = "one equals one";
        //my_assert(1 == 1, msg.c_str()); // triggers static_assert
    }

    {
        const int msg = 3;
        my_assert(1 == 1, msg); // should trigger static_assert
    }
}
```

As you can see, the testing is done via the tests provided by the type_traits header, and, 
*mostly*, this code works as intended (tested with gcc 4.7.2). However, it doesn't specifically look for string literals as much as it just rejects common things that a programmer might use in place.

The solution I have may be good enough for the example above, but I'd like to use this, or a similar technique in other situations as well.

So the question is, how do I reliably use type_traits (or another standard mechanism) to static_assert on *anything* except a string literal?

Comment: Do you actually want to display a message when an assert fails? If so then please post another question. The standard `assert()` macro is pretty useless in my opinion but there are really neat ways to write your own, displaying a message together with the values of the variables involved.

Comment: @Ali thanks, but my question has very little to do with `assert()` other than that it was a motivating vehicle to demonstrate one reason the answer to the question could be useful. I alreay get a great message when the assert fails using the standard one provided by gcc/libc. There are of course more sophisticated ways to do assertions, but that's not really the point of my question -- as I said, I'm interested in how to detect a string literal vs other things. (My own answer below seems to do the trick pretty closely.)

Comment: OK, I though you needed a fancy assert. Well, good luck!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the best I could get, which appears to reject anything I throw at it, but still accepts literal strings:

```
#define my_assert(test, message)\
    static_assert(\
        (\
             std::is_convertible      <decltype(message), const char *>::value &&\
            !std::is_rvalue_reference <decltype(message)>::value &&\
            !std::is_pointer          <decltype(message)>::value &&\
            !std::is_array            <decltype(message)>::value &&\
            !std::is_class            <decltype(message)>::value\
        ),\
        "string literal required"\
    );\
    assert((message, (test)))
```

I'd be very interested to know if this *actually* is exhaustively correct, and/or if there is a simpler way to do this detection.

Answer (score 2):

'decltype("some string")' of a string literal returns "const char (&)[n]" type.
Thus, it seems there is more succinct, in comparison with [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14805137), way to detect it:

```
template<typename T>
struct IsStringLiteral :
    std::is_same<
        T,
        std::add_lvalue_reference_t<const char[std::extent_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>]>
    >
{};
```

([online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84002237e7bcaf5c))

Note: it is possible to create a variable of `const char (&)[n]` type which will fool this implementation:

```
const auto &msg1 = "some string";

const char c[4]{};
auto& msg2 = c;

// msg1 and msg2 is recognized by IsStringLiteral as string literals
static_assert(is_string_literal<decltype(msg1)>::value, "");
static_assert(is_string_literal<decltype(msg2)>::value, "");
```