# Is a way to know if a variable is a numeric literal or constexpr at compile time using type_traits?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr, type-traits

I'm working with templates and compile-time checks, and I would like to know if there is a way to know at compile-time if a variable is a numeric literal:

```
is_numeric_literal_v<10> // result: true

constexpr int Val = 5;
is_numeric_literal_v<Val> // result: true

int value = 10;
is_numeric_literal_v<value> // result: false
```

Is there something like that?
I have been trying with type_traits and template specializations but nothing :(

For string literal, it is possible:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool 
IsStringLiteral()
{
    //  const char (&)[n]

    return 
    std::is_convertible_v       <T, const char *> &&
    !std::is_rvalue_reference_v <T> &&
    !std::is_pointer_v          <T> &&
    !std::is_array_v            <T> &&
    !std::is_class_v            <T>;
}

int main()
{
    IsStringLiteral<decltype("Literal text")>(); // result: true
    std::string str("aaaa");
    IsStringLiteral<decltype(str)>(); // result: false
}
```

EDIT: The question isn't if the value is a constexpr (I don't need that) because in the case of a string literal I don't know if it's a constexpr (nor I need to know it) but I can check the value in compile-time. I wanted to ask if there is the same for numeric literals.

Comment: “For string literal, it is possible” — Maybe, but your code doesn’t do this, it tests for something completely different. You could implement the same code for the “integer literal” case which distinguishes between `int` and `SomeIntWrapperClass`.

Comment: I want to test if it a numeric literal, to use it to do more compile-time checking. If I know that the value is for example "512", I can check if it exceeds the buffer size, for example. All in compile time. The C++20 tell me if it is constexpr inside the function, that is too late. I want to know it before, and just in that case, do another checks.

Comment: "As of 2017, [...] there is, to my knowledge, no way to detect whether an expression is usable as a constant expression" --- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47538175/5470596

Comment: @YSC Yes, I know, but for a string literal, I can get it at compile-time, and with that info I could get the size of the literal. With a numeric literal, instead of a string literal, should also be possible  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48141640/13459484

Comment: The closest thing we have is GCC's `__builtin_constant_p`.

Comment: thanks, but __builtin_constant_p() doesn't work well, it gives true just if the variable has a value set. I though here could be the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936549/constexpr-overloading/60714976#60714976 but not. Sadly my question was closed :(

Comment: Why you need this? For me this looks like [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @MarekR I am making a compile-time checkers. For example: sprintf(buffer, 50, "text..."); I can know the sizeof the buffer, and I want to check in compile-time if the 50 is bigger than the buffer size. I want to achieve that in compile-time, so I just need to know if it is a numerical literal. If a know that, I can use constexpr int Value = Arg1;

Comment: @Aitorhub: even in the linked question, it doesn't detect string literal, only `const char(&)[N]` and `const char buffer[1] = get_random_char()` has correct type, but is not `constexpr`.

Comment: You might add overload to your function which take `std::integral_constant`

Comment: @Jarod42 About the const char(&)[N] even if it isn't constexpr I can get the "N" and with that the exact element size at compile-time. For that reason I say it before that I don't need to know if it's constexpr. About your second answer, the point is to differentiate if the integral is known at compile-time. What can I do with std::integral_constant? Maybe with std::enable_if<>? I don't know.

Comment: I meant: `void foo(int); template <int N>void foo(std::integral_constant<int, N>) { static_assert(my_compile_check(N)); foo(N);}`. but user has to call `foo(std::integral_constant<int, 42>{});` (or with appropriate UDL `foo(42_c);`).

Comment: You might want to differentiate `const int&` from `int&`. the later cannot be `constexpr`, whereas the former might...

Comment: Thanks. That may help. For string literal is it possible. I can do: template<typename T>
struct IsStringLiteral :
    std::is_same<
        T,
        std::add_lvalue_reference_t<const char[std::extent_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>]>
    >
{}; with I know if it is a literal string or not. But, with numeric value not. I would like to do: ok = IsNumberLiteral<42>(); // ok == true and ok = IsNumberLiteral<uValue>(); // ok == false

Comment: Nothing, It is not possible. Thanks for helping

Comment: Your use wrong phrasing, you cannot detect string literal, but you can detect `const char[N]` type (with deduced `N`).

Comment: True, and if a can detect the const char[N], I can read that N and check the size in compile-time. I want something similar for the number, to be able to detect it

Comment: In the same way, with numbers types you can differentiate `std::uint32_t` from `std::uint16_t`... but that won't help you. As it is the value than you want to check.

Comment: Exactly @Jarod42. Or to be more precise, I want to know if is constexpr, and just if that case, get the value at compile-time (something easy thanks to type_traits).